# How to add a changeset comment as part of script

Tags: rtc

When creating a changeset I receive an ID which I can then use to assign a changeset comment :

```
scm create changeset
scm changeset comment <id_returned_by_create> my comment
```

When creating a changeset can i assign an alias/id to the changeset ? This is so I can add the comment to a changeset as part of a script. Or is there another way of adding a changeset comment as part of a script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/77403/autobuilds-scm-changeset-associate-command), I don't think you can define your own alias:

> When you run scm status, you should see the outgoing change set. There will be a number next to it.
>   This is the alias. It is a temporary id given to the change set for the duration of your session.